# How to export data from excel file and import into to sql database?

Tags: sql, excel, import, export

Is there a method to do this ? I have like 6000 rows in excel, and it would take months to import it into the sql database.

For example there are : **Column A** and **Column B** in excel and I'd like to import it into **Column A** and **Column B** into an sql table.

Thanks!

Comment: Sugestion, save the excel as CSV then use any programming language to parse it into inserts -> run script!

Comment: I know MS Office Access has a function to import a db from an excel sheet. You might want to take a look at that

Comment: Which database? MySQL, SQL Server, DB2 ?  Anyways, first of all export required data in csv format ( In Excel, save as .csv file ), and then import that csv file into the database. ( Different database have different way to do it. )

Comment: It's Excel 2007. I'd like to import it via phpmyadmin, I guess it's a MySQL server. I'm going to try this out, and reply back with my progress. Thanks guys!

Comment: Another alternative would be to simply build a script directly in Excel then run this in your database. Use a formula like this and copy it down your 6000 rows: `="INSERT INTO MYTABLE (COL_A, COL_B) VALUES('" & A2 & "','" & B2 & "');"`

Comment: I think this would be the most simple, by creamyegg, but I'm not sure how to make the script. A2 and B2 would be the 2nd row from the first two columns in excel? I would like to insert all what's in the A column and B and C from excel into column1, column2, column3 in my sql table.

Comment: Original poster doesn't say what RDBMS he's using, but don't MS-SqlServer and other DB's have a tool like Oracle's `sqlldr.exe` which imports delimited plain text data files (e.g. CSV)?  I recall using such a built-in tool for MSSQL a few years back.  Generating the `insert` statements using Excel formulas is an even more straightforward approach.

Comment: This is a common occurrence and there's plenty of information online. The MySQL site has a guide (registration required), or you can [view it here](http://wenku.baidu.com/view/87af11cea1c7aa00b52acbd7.html), and there are [lots of blog posts](http://blog.tjitjing.com/index.php/2008/02/import-excel-data-into-mysql-in-5-easy.html), as well. There's even a Youtube guide. Also, consider the [CSV Storage Engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/csv-storage-engine.html).

Comment: 6000 records is not that many at all and should never take months to import.

Comment: I forgot to write **manually, one by one from the admin CP**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach through VBA that I used for a book database. Not too tough as long as you can establish a connection to the DB. Obviously you will have to tweek it a bit for it to work with your database and your data. In particular you will have to adjust the sql string to connect you your database (change "test.yourdatabase")

```
Sub addBook(title As String, author As String, link As String, foundBy As String)
  ' for this code to work, you need a reference to the MS Activex
  ' data access objects
  ' Tools|References... microsoft activex data objects 2.8 (or newer)

  Dim cn As New Connection
  Dim cs As String
  Dim un as String
  Dim pw as String
  Dim sql As String


  cs = "DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=websql.org,5901;DATABASE=websql" 'connection string 

  un = username 'this is the username for the database

  pw = password 'this is the password for the database account

  cn.Open cs, Range("un").Value, Range("pw").Value


  sql = "insert into test.yourdatabase(searchtitle, searchAuthor, link, foundBy, foundTime) values(" & _
  "'<TITLE>', " & _
  "'<AUTHOR>', " & _
  "'<LINK>', " & _
  "'<FOUNDBY>', " & _
  "getdate());"

  'replace statements are for correcting any ' that occure in the titles or names

  sql = Replace(sql, "<TITLE>", Replace(title, "'", "''"))
  sql = Replace(sql, "<AUTHOR>", Replace(author, "'", "''"))
  sql = Replace(sql, "<LINK>", Replace(link, "'", "''"))
  sql = Replace(sql, "<FOUNDBY>", Replace(foundBy, "'", "''"))

  'Debug.Print sql

 cn.Execute sql

  cn.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `MySQL`, it provides a direct way to export data into the database: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-for-excel/en/mysql-for-excel-export.html

If you are using `SQLite`/`PostGres`, there is a commercial offering from Devart to do the same:

https://www.devart.com/excel-addins/postgresql.html

https://www.devart.com/excel-addins/sqlite.html